# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
Activity

    package com.bpd.lemongroupchat.tabactivities.subactivity;


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.bpd.lemongroupchat.R;
import com.bpd.lemongroupchat.utils.DialogUtils;
import com.bpd.lemongroupchat.utils.GraphicsUtil;
import com.bpd.lemongroupchat.utils.ImageHelper;
import com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService;
import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBDialog;
import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBDialogType;
import com.quickblox.core.QBEntityCallbackImpl;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CreateOrUpdateGroupActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    Button createBtn;
    ImageView groupImageIcon;   
    SharedPreferences sp;
    String user="";
    ImageView groupImage;
    TextView inviteUser,groupCode;
    EditText firstNameEdit;

    //Spinner ageSpinner;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;

    /************QuickBlox*************/
    Bitmap imgBitmap=null;
    String firstNameEditStr="",imagePath="";
    protected ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ImageHelper imageHelper ;
    private Bitmap photo=null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.create_update_group_screen);

        sp=this.getSharedPreferences("lemon_messenger", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        user=sp.getString("CREATE_UPDATE", user);

        Log.d("Profile", "1");

        // set circle bitmap
        groupImage          =   (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.groupPic);
        groupImageIcon      =   (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.groupImgIcon);
        createBtn           =   (Button) findViewById(R.id.createBtn);
        inviteUser          =   (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inviteUser);
        groupCode           =   (TextView) findViewById(R.id.groupCode);
        firstNameEdit       =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstNameEdit);

        progressDialog = DialogUtils.getProgressDialog(this);        
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");

        if(user.trim().equals("1"))
        {
            groupCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            createBtn.setText("Update");
        }
        else
        {
            groupCode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            createBtn.setText("Create");
        }

        createBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        groupImageIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

    }   

    @Override   
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.createBtn: 
                                firstNameEditStr    =   firstNameEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                                if(user.trim().equals("1"))
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gorup Successfully Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                else
                                {   
                        //          if(imgBitmap!=null)                     
                        //          {
                                        if(!firstNameEditStr.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                                        {   
                                            progressDialog.show();
                                            createGroupChatMethod();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select a group name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                        //          }
                        //          else
                        //          {
                        //              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please choose a group photo first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //          }                   
                                }
                                break;
            case R.id.groupImgIcon:
                                selectImage();
                                break;
        }
    }
      protected void createGroupChatMethod() 
      {
          // code will be here
      }


      private void selectImage() {

            final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo from Camera", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateOrUpdateGroupActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (options[item].equals("Take Photo from Camera"))
                    {
                        // call android default camera
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
                        // ******** code for crop image
//                      intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
//                      intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
//                      intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
//                      intent.putExtra("outputX", 120);
//                      intent.putExtra("outputY", 120);

                        try {

                            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        // Do nothing for now
                        }
                    }
                    else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                    {
//                      Intent intent = new Intent();
//                      // call android default gallery
//                      intent.setType("image/*");
//                      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//                      // ******** code for crop image
//                      intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
//                      intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
//                      intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
//                      intent.putExtra("outputX", 120);
//                      intent.putExtra("outputY", 120);
//
//                      try {
//
//                      intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
//                      startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
//                      "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
//
//                      } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
//                      // Do nothing for now
//                      }
                        // GET IMAGE FROM THE GALLERY
//                      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//                      intent.setType("image/*");
//
//                      Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a Picture");
//                      startActivityForResult(chooser, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(i, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
                    }
                    else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
        {    
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                System.out.println("Data: " +  data.getStringExtra("path"));
            if(!data.getStringExtra("path").trim().equals(null))
            {
            System.out.println("Data: " +  data.getStringExtra("path"));
            if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
                if (data != null) {
                    Bitmap photo1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 

                    // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
                    Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo1);

                    // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
                    String pathCam= getRealPathFromURI(tempUri);

                    try {
                        photo = imageHelper.getScaledBitmap(pathCam);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(photo != null){
                        GraphicsUtil graphicUtil = new GraphicsUtil();
                        groupImage.setImageBitmap(graphicUtil.getCircleBitmap(photo, 150));     

                    }                   
                }
            }

            if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
                if (data != null) {

                     Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        String path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();

                    try {
                        photo = imageHelper.getScaledBitmap(path);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(photo != null){
                        GraphicsUtil graphicUtil = new GraphicsUtil();
                        groupImage.setImageBitmap(graphicUtil.getCircleBitmap(photo, 150)); 

                    }
                }
            }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Null Data: " +  data.getStringExtra("path"));
            }
            }
        } 

        public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
             ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
             String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
             return Uri.parse(path);
        }

        public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
             Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
             cursor.moveToFirst(); 
             int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
             return cursor.getString(idx); 
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_back, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.back_btn) {

              finish();
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

Log Cat Error:

```
    10-28 18:31:36.360: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17544): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
10-28 18:31:39.205: I/System.out(17544): Data: null
10-28 18:31:39.205: D/AndroidRuntime(17544): Shutting down VM
10-28 18:31:39.205: W/dalvikvm(17544): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41972700)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/72092 (has extras) }} to activity {com.bpd.lemongroupchat/com.bpd.lemongroupchat.tabactivities.subactivity.CreateOrUpdateGroupActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3500)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3543)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:159)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at com.bpd.lemongroupchat.tabactivities.subactivity.CreateOrUpdateGroupActivity.onActivityResult(CreateOrUpdateGroupActivity.java:244)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3496)
10-28 18:31:39.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17544):    ... 11 more
```

How the error occurs? But the same code works for other activity, but there is no concept of Menu

Comment: try `if(data.getStringExtra("path") != null && !data.getStringExtra("path").trim().equals(null))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stupid. Please check my code, I just miss this line

```
imageHelper = new ImageHelper(this);
```

ImageHelper is a class, which I forgot to intialize, so for this reason it's gives NPE .

Thanks to all who try to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

before you doing anything with your data you should first check..
make this check that the request code is equal what you send and the result code is equal to ok and final thing make sure that your data is not null

```
 (requestCode==what_you_assign&&data!=null&&resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.getStringExtra("path").trim().equals(null)
```

This line is problematic, you cannot call `trim()` (or any other method) on `null`.. Since your console shows

> Data: null

it means `data.getStringExtra("path")` returns `null`, so what you are trying to do basically comes down to `null.trim()`, which throws an NPE. Just check if `data.getStringExtra("path")` returns `null` in your if statement (remove the call to trim).

**SOLUTION** : replace

```
if(!data.getStringExtra("path").trim().equals(null))
```

by

```
if(data != null && data.getExtras("data")!=null)
```

The whole `onActivityResult` method would be better rewritten like so :

- check if resultCode is RESULT_OK
- check if data != null
- switch on requestCode
- inside every switch case (every requestCode you want to handle, check
  if data contains the data you want
- use data

Comment: I know data comes null, but how I avoid this, I need solution. This chking already I have been done.

Comment: "I know data comes null" : if you knew, why calling a method on null ?? "how I avoid this" : You can't, your user can always choose to press back, you need to handle the fact that it CAN be null. The "chking" (I'm assuming you're referring to checking if data is null) was indeed done, but not in a correct way, which caused the error you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure data isn't null first and then `data.getStringExtra("path")!=null` . If you were trying to make sure it had text you could check the length of the trimmed string after verifying its not null.